# Redirecting output into existing (g)vim instance

Tags: vim, redirection

Is it possible to redirect the output of a process (in bash) into an existing instance of (g)vim?

Something like:

```
cat myfile1.txt | awk 'print $1' | gvim -
```

Then I might start a new window inside my vim with `:vne` and want to fill it with the output from some other process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example works but it can't be used as is from your terminal to open a second output in a second window.

You can put the output of your command in the active buffer from within Vim itself with

```
:read !cat myfile1.txt | awk 'print $1'
```

That's the simplest solution I can think of.

You can also use GVim as a server and send it your output, see `:h clientserver`.

Comment: I can't figure out why process substitution won't work with the --remote option. `gvim --remote somefile.txt` does what you'd think, but `gvim --remote <( cat somefile.txt )` opens an empty file.

Comment: `gvim --servername NAME --remote-send ':read !cat file.txt<CR>'` works.

Comment: `gvim --servername NAME --remote-send ':vnew | :read !cat file.txt<CR>'` works too.